# Selenium XPath Click Load More Button Until Gone

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape apartment names and apartment addresses from this website: https://www.rentcollegepads.com/off-campus-housing/mississippi-state/search. I am new to scraping and was wondering if someone could help me. Thanks

I am able to click the "Load More" button once with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv

file_name = 'Test'

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

url = 'https://www.rentcollegepads.com/off-campus-housing/mississippi-state/search'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(6)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block' and contains(., 'Load More')]"))).click()

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

driver.quit()

name = soup.find("h3", class_="ellipsis").get_text(strip=True)

address = soup.find("span", class_="ellipsis").get_text(strip=True)

print(name)
print(address)
```

My current obstacle is I need to click the Load More Button an undefined number of times per search. How would I click the "Load More" button every time it is visible until it is gone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `while loop` to click untill it finishes the load more button

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

url = 'https://www.rentcollegepads.com/off-campus-housing/mississippi-state/search'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)


while True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find("h3", class_="ellipsis").get_text(strip=True)

    address = soup.find("span", class_="ellipsis").get_text(strip=True)

    print(name)
    print(address)
 
    try:     
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="loadMoreBtn col-sm-10"]/button'))
        pos= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="loadMoreBtn col-sm-10"]/button'))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break
```